# Access to undeclared static property when resending verification email

Tags: laravel

I am working with Laravel as my backend for my Vue project and as such had to modify the verification email code. I am now running into an error when resending the email.

Error: `"Access to undeclared static property: App\Notifications\VerifyEmail::$toMailCallback"`

If I remove `if (static::$toMailCallback) {
             return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable);
         }`

It sends the email, but I get the error with the code present.

```
namespace App\Notifications;

...
class VerifyEmail extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    ...

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
     public function toMail($notifiable)
     {
         if (static::$toMailCallback) {
             return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable);
         }
         return (new MailMessage)
             ->subject('Verify Email Address')
             ->line('Please click the button below to verify your email address.')
             ->action(
                 'Verify Email Address',
                 $this->verificationUrl($notifiable)
             )
             ->line('If you did not create an account, no further action is required.');
     }

     /**
     * Get the verification URL for the given notifiable.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return string
     */
    protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {

      $prefix = config('app.front_url') . config('app.email_verify_url');
      $temporarySignedURL = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
          'verification.verify', Carbon::now()->addMinutes(60), ['id' => $notifiable->getKey()]
      );

      // I use urlencode to pass a link to my frontend.
      return $prefix . urlencode($temporarySignedURL);

    }

    /**
     * Set a callback that should be used when building the notification mail message.
     *
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return void
     */
    public static function toMailUsing($callback)
    {
        static::$toMailCallback = $callback;
    }

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spent a few hours trying to figure it out then find out I deleted a line of code...

`public static $toMailCallback;`

Forgot to declare it. Solved.